# 'New-ShardMapManager' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet trying to access through powershell

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, powershell-4.0, azure-elastic-scale, azure-elastic-sharding

Steps I used:
Login-AzureRmAccount -- I ran this cmdlet in Powershell in admin mode
once logged I ran this below query

```
New-ShardMapManager -UserName 'user_name' -Password 'enterd password' -SqlServerName 'server_name.database.windows.net' -SqlDatabaseName 'Elastic_poc_db'
```

I am getting following error :

```
New-ShardMapManager : The term 'New-ShardMapManager' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-ShardMapManager:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am Using Powershell 4 version

Comment: Is this still available in powershell 4? Haven't used it myself but have you tried with `New-AzureRmSqlElasticPool` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.sql/v1.0.12/new-azurermsqlelasticpool

Answer (score 1):

New-ShardMapManager is not part of the Azure Resource Manager, it is a separate download which you can get from here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-DB-Elastic-731883db

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem much more recently than the above post, and the information in previous replies is out of date. My solution may contain anti-practices, but it worked for me.

1. Add the elastic client NuGet Package to your PowerShell. The version I used is the current one as of this posting.

In a PowerShell prompt running as Administrator, run the following:

```
Install-Package -Name Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client -RequiredVersion 2.3.0 -SkipDependencies -Force -Source NuGet.org
```

2. Copy files into your PowerShell modules folder structure.

- Create a subfolder of your Documents\PowerShell\Modules folder. I
  used \ShardManagement.
- Copy the DLL installed by Install-Package into
  the folder. Mine was here: C:\Program
  Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client.2.3.0\lib\net451\Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client.dll.
- Copy the .psm1 file ShardManagement.psm1 from github in
  elastic-db-tools/Samples/PowerShell/ShardManagement at [the GitHub Elastic DB Tools repo](https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/tree/master/Samples/PowerShell/ShardManagement) to the same modules folder.

3. Import the module.

From the same PowerShell prompt you used in step 1, run this:

```
Import-Module ShardManagement
```

You should now be able to run New-ShardMapManager and its siblings in PowerShell.